# How get current positions by Binance API, Python

Tags: python-3.x, binance

Can someone say how to get current positions by python-binance? Like "WAVESUSDT" on screen.

[image]

Here is the documentation, but I can't find there this method. Could someone help me, please?
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html#account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found, yeah!

```
client = Client(api,key)
client.futures_account()['positions']
```

Comment: does it returning all the current open position of the orders ?

Comment: It returns all posible positions, but if, for example, 'maintMargin' of the symbol doesn't equal to zero, it's means, that the position with this symbol is open.

Comment: you can get open contracts f.e. with ```next(obj for obj in self.client.futures_account()['positions'] if obj['symbol'] == 'ETHUSDT')['positionAmt']```

Answer (score 5):

I have got the open positions from this url

https://testnet.binancefuture.com/fapi/v2/positionRisk?

(Note if no position is open it will return 2 dummy position)

```
return await axios
    .get(`https://testnet.binancefuture.com/fapi/v2/positionRisk?symbol=${token_pair}&timestamp=${timestamp}&signature=${signature}`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-MBX-APIKEY': api_key
        }
    })
```

Comment: But this is TESTNET, not a real market, am I not right?

Comment: Yes but you can use the same approach for the mainnet as  well but the endpoint will be different.

Comment: Yes, but why positionSide is BOTH? It should be either Long or Short

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a single symbol's position information with python, you can use `get_position_risk()` method like this.

```
from binance.um_futures import UMFutures

um_futures_client = UMFutures(key="testnet_api_key", secret="testnet_secret_key", base_url="https://testnet.binancefuture.com")

resp = um_futures_client.get_position_risk(
    symbol='WAVESUSDT'
)

print(resp)

# [{'symbol': 'WAVESUSDT', 'positionAmt': '0.0', 'entryPrice': '0.0', 'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxNotionalValue': '25000', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'LONG', 'notional': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0', 'updateTime': 0}, {'symbol': 'WAVESUSDT', 'positionAmt': '0.0', 'entryPrice': '0.0', 'markPrice': '0.00000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxNotionalValue': '25000', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'SHORT', 'notional': '0', 'isolatedWallet': '0', 'updateTime': 0}]
```